# Convert JavaScript Object / JSON into PHP Array Trouble

Tags: javascript, php, json

This question is not related at all to the mentioned duplicate answer/question...

I have a large list of over 1,000 items in JavaScript i this format...

```
var plugins = [
    {
        name: "Roundabout - Interactive, turntable-like areas",
        url: "http:\/\/fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/",
        tag: "slide"
    },
    {
        name: "Slides - Simple slideshow plugin for jQuery",
        url: "http://slidesjs.com/",
        tag: "slide"
    }

    ......lots more
]
```

**My goal is to import them into a PHP array like this....**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Roundabout - Interactive, turntable-like areas/
            [url] => http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/
            [tag] => slide
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Slides - Simple slideshow plugin for jQuery
            [url] => http://slidesjs.com/
            [tag] => slide
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Orbit - jQuery Image Slider Plugin
            [url] => http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin/
            [tag] => slide
        )

)
```

---

I tried using PHP's `json_decode()` function however the source JS does not have the keys wrapped in `"` so it does not work.

When I manually added `"`'s around the keys and some backslashes then PHP `json_decode()` works....

```
$json = '[{
    "name": "Roundabout - Interactive, turntable-like areas/",
    "url": "http:\/\/fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/",
    "tag": "slide"
},
{
    "name": "Slides - Simple slideshow plugin for jQuery",
    "url": "http:\/\/slidesjs.com\/",
    "tag": "slide"
},
{
    "name": "Orbit - jQuery Image Slider Plugin",
    "url": "http:\/\/www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin/",
    "tag": "slide"
}]';

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

---

The issue though is my large list does not have the keys wrapped in quotes so I need a way to automate it.

**Could someone help me to achieve the end goal since my attempts have all failed so far please?**

Comment: You're trying to parse Javascript source code? Why is the data only available as Javascript source code? Can you not get the data in actual JSON or any other format?

Comment: It works if you apply `JSON.stringify(obj)` in your object before the PHP function `json_decode`.

Comment: @Marcelo That would require Javascript to be executed before PHP, which I'm not sure is feasible/applicable/realistic here.

Comment: @Jason Please clarify the situation you're in that necessitates you parsing Javascript object literals...

Comment: @deceze The reason behind this is because I have a JS bookmarks app which the creator generated a JS file with the source data in that format.  I build a database backend with PHP to store the records and I am going to have my PHP DB generate the correct output instead of using the authors manually updated massive file of bookmarks.  So this will be a 1 time operation to convert that file to PHP array so I can loop over it and insert the records into my DB

Comment: @JasonDavis how are you sending the JSON to the PHP?

Comment: How you sending this data to PHP? Show the function that does it.

Comment: Can't you simply run this through actual Javascript then and have *it* generate the output you need? Even if that's just JSON encoding it once?

Comment: Right now that data is just in a JS File so I am not sending it to PHP.  Other than my test  to store it in a PHP variable and convert it into PHP array.  I just need to process the JS file of data 1 time so my new PHP backend can insert all the old records in the JS object into a database

Comment: @JasonDavis So how are you *processing* the JS file?

Comment: @deceze using JavaScript is an option, anyway to get the result I need for this 1 time operation is good for me

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am not touching the JS file at the moment.  I copy/pasted 3/4 items from the JS file into a PHP variable for testing so far

Comment: If it is a one time operation, you can use JavaScript to stringify and therefore use PHP to iterate the data, I believe.

Comment: @JasonDavis Just use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com) to convert it to valid JSON then.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I just saw your answer before delted...I do think that was the valid solution!

Comment: @JasonDavis I have undeleted the answer.!

Comment: So, just copy and paste this into your browser's Javascript console, `JSON.stringify` it, copy it into PHP/text file, done. If you need to make this action repeatable, write a tiny script on Node.js.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thanks.  BTW JSONLint didn't work as it throws errors.  I think your solution will do the trick though.  Thanks for all the ideas and help everyone!

Comment: @JasonDavis yes... It threw errors...

Comment: @deceze genius thanks

Comment: whoever changed my question to say there is an answer on the other question...didn't read my damn question!  It's not even related!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem can be solved manually by taking this method, as having said that the JSON presented here is valid, it is better to use either console or something to make the JSON valid for everywhere not only in JavaScript by using:

```
plugins = JSON.stringify(plugins);
```

This will make the `plugins` to look like:

```
"[{"name":"Roundabout - Interactive, turntable-like areas","url":"http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/","tag":"slide"},{"name":"Slides - Simple slideshow plugin for jQuery","url":"http://slidesjs.com/","tag":"slide"}]"
```

Removing the quotes and putting it in [**JSONLint**](http://jsonlint.com) will give out a valid JSON like the below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Roundabout - Interactive, turntable-like areas",
        "url": "http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/",
        "tag": "slide"
    },
    {
        "name": "Slides - Simple slideshow plugin for jQuery",
        "url": "http://slidesjs.com/",
        "tag": "slide"
    }
]
```

Now the best way is to copy this output and save it in the text.

Comment: That assumes some sort of "sending" is going on here...

Comment: @deceze How does JavaScript then **send** the content to PHP?

Comment: I have no idea! Sounds to me like OP is trying to parse a Javascript source code file of some sort or another.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, we don't know if the OP can use JavaScript here. It was what we were discussing in comments above.

Comment: @MarceloCamargo `var`, `JavaScript` and the OP has tagged JavaScript too.

Comment: `stringify` worked http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/stq251xu/

Comment: dont feel bad my quest got 4 downvotes even though I took the time to post a clear question with code samples and showed that I put in the effort trying a few solutions that failed before asking the question!  I'm a bit confused but it's nothing to lose sleep over...I got my answer and thats all that mattered to me...im a grown up ;)

Comment: @JasonDavis Have a look at the updated answer now.